# вывод pdf вместо csv wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

не могу понять как сделать вывод pdf вместо csv?
Есть такой код

```
function rtec_event_csv() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['rtec_my_events_csv'] ) ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
            wp_die( 'You did not do this the right way!' );
        }
        $nonce = $_POST['rtec_csv_export_nonce'];

        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'rtec_csv_export' ) ) {
            die ( 'You did not do this the right way!' );
        }

        rtec_my_events_csv();
    } elseif ( isset( $_POST['rtec_event_csv'] ) ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
            wp_die( 'You did not do this the right way!' );
        }
        $nonce = $_POST['rtec_csv_export_nonce'];

        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'rtec_csv_export' ) ) {
            die ( 'You did not do this the right way!' );
        }

        $use_utf8_fix = apply_filters( 'rtec_utf8_fix', false );

        if ( $use_utf8_fix ) {
            require_once RTEC_PLUGIN_DIR . 'vendor/ForceUTF8/Encoding.php';
            $encoding = new RTEC_Encoding();
        }

        $rtec = RTEC();
        $form = $rtec->form->instance();

        $event_obj = new RTEC_Admin_Event();
        $form->build_form( (int)$_GET['id'] );

        $event_obj->build_admin_event( (int)$_GET['id'], 'csv', '', $form );
        $event_meta = $event_obj->event_meta;
        $venue_title = $event_meta['venue_title'];

        $event_meta_string = array(
            array( $event_meta['title'] ) ,

            array( date_i18n( str_replace( ',', ' ', rtec_get_date_time_format() ), strtotime( $event_meta['start_date'] ) ) ),
            array( date_i18n( str_replace( ',', ' ', rtec_get_date_time_format() ), strtotime( $event_meta['end_date'] ) ) ),
            array( $venue_title ),
            array_map( 'stripslashes', $event_obj->labels )
        );

        $file_name = str_replace( ' ', '-', substr( $event_meta['title'], 0, 10 ) ) . '_' . str_replace( ' ', '-', substr( $event_meta['venue_title'], 0, 10 ) ) . '_'  . date_i18n( 'm.d', strtotime( $event_meta['start_date'] ) );

        // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
        header( 'Content-Encoding: UTF-8' );
        header( 'Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . str_replace( ',', '', $file_name ) . '.csv"' );
        echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM

        // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
        $output = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
        foreach ( $event_meta_string as $meta ) {
            fputcsv( $output, $meta );
        }
        foreach ( $event_obj->registrants_data as $registration ) {

            $time_format = rtec_get_time_format();
            $formatted_registration = array( 'registration_date' => date_i18n( 'F jS, ' . $time_format, strtotime( $registration['registration_date'] ) + rtec_get_time_zone_offset() ) );

            foreach ( $event_obj->column_label as $column => $label ) {

                if ( isset( $registration[$column] ) ) {
                    $value = stripslashes( $registration[$column] );
                } else if ( isset( $registration[$column.'_name'] ) ) {
                    $value = stripslashes( $registration[$column.'_name'] );
                } else if ( isset( $registration['custom'][$column] ) ) {
                    $value = stripslashes( $registration['custom'][$column]['value'] );
                } else if ( isset( $registration['custom'][$label] ) ) {
                    $value = stripslashes( $registration['custom'][$label] );
                }

                $value = $use_utf8_fix ? $encoding->fixUTF8( $value ) : $value;

                $formatted_registration[$column] = $value;

            }

            fputcsv( $output, $formatted_registration );

        }

        fclose( $output );

        die();
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'rtec_event_csv' );
```

хочу при нажатии получать те же данные что и csv но в формате pdf ?

Comment: Нужно либо конвертировать csv в pdf (если вдруг зачем-то нужен csv), либо изначально создавать pdf файл.

Comment: @Simon а как это сделать?

Comment: Как в php создать pdf файл написано в миллиарде результатов поиска и тут и в гугле.